# binding transformer #formatNumber cannot used for field in create/edit form

Tags: google-app-maker

When I apply #formatNumber('00%') for a field in create form, ex.20%, the real value saved in model is 20 instead of 0.2 which is expected.

I have a field in create form, it's for a ratio in percentage, for that field I set value as `@widget.datasource.ratio#formatNumber('00%')`, this forces user to input a percentage and show value in percentage, however I find that the real value saved in model is number before percentage, ex. when user input 20%, a number 20 saved in databased instead of 20%.

So far, it looks that #formatNumber('00%') in percentage mode can only be used in read mode to show a number in percentage, ex. for a number 0.2 in databased, it can be shown as 20% in a table when that transformer is applied.

How can I use a #formatNumber to force percentage input and save the real number/value in databased? or is there a best practice for this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can with a series of transformations change the value of the input before the creation of records.
on the submit button of the form in "onClick" make a custom action :

```
widget.root.descendants.Field.value = ((parseFloat(widget.root.descendants.Field.value.toString().replace("%","")))/100).toString()+"%";
widget.datasource.createItem();
```

Replace all "Field" by the input name.